# JCA sample implementations

Tags: java, jca

I need to develop a JCA adapter and am looking for some references. I searched on Amazon, and found only 2 JCA books and one of them has pretty bad comments. So I guess that left me with only one book to refer to.

So I would like to know if there is any sample implementation of JCA adapter that will help my development. I searched on Google but managed to find some very simple examples only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JCA is almost the most complex JEE spec I know...Which sample do you need? inbound or outbound?

Comment: Hi Shengyuan Lu! I need to implement both inbound and outbound. It will be great if you could provide both.Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I developed adapter I used example from JBoss. 
I believe this is the link:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/An_Overview_of_the_JBossCX_Architecture-A_Sample_Skeleton_JCA_Resource_Adaptor.html

Good luck. Be ready to have the hard days! :(

Answer (score 6):

Inbound sample at google code: http://code.google.com/p/jca-sockets/

Other outbound on javaworld: [Build your own J2EE Connector Architecture adapter](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0201-jca2.html)

Hope they could help.

As Alex said, '*Have the hard days!*':)

Answer (score 6):

The link that Alex provided seems to be a useful sample implementation. But I couldn't find the source code at the link mentioned in that document.

With the help of Google, I found source codes of that sample JCA adapter at below link. In case if there is anyone looking for the same thing, I posted it here.

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-cvs-commits/2006-November/011464.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Legend! I just downloaded JBoss 4 to not find this code in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

I had also big problems to find examples and documentation. I wrote a small tcp server [inbound resource adapter](https://github.com/joe-bookwood/inbound-ra-example) example for wildfly10 and EE7. I used this examples as a base for my questions in this forum. I described in the `readme.md` the use of the Iron Jacamar JCA source generator. This tool is very useful. I put also useful documentation links to the end of the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider  [Adam Bien's connectorZ](http://connectorz.adam-bien.com).

If you want something more specific to Jboss you may consider  Red Hat's [Iron Jacamar](http://www.ironjacamar.org), which is Jboss JCA implementation.  There are releases compatible with JCA 1.0, 1.5, 1,6 and 1.7 with each one being backwards compatible. The download includes also  a sample directory with 4 simple examples.  Also  at Iron Jacamar you can find a very interesting code generator and a plugin for eclipse, both of which are able to generate complete JCA adapter skeletons.

Answer (score 0):

The Glassfish samples have a Java Mail JCA connector for different EE versions.

Here the Java EE 6 version:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-samples/tree/master/ws/javaee6/connectors/apps/mailconnector

Also, there is the Cuckoo Resource Adapter for SAP at https://sourceforge.net/p/cuckoo-ra/home/Home/